# Send the Menu key (Right click)

Tags: c#, winforms

How I can send the menu key (also known as the Context Menu key)?
The menu key does the same action as the right-click, but its on your keyboard and the menu will appear at the place that is selected (not at the place of your mouse).

[image: Photo of the Menu key]

I tried Shift+f10, but doesnt work

```
Sendkeys.Send({})
```

So what do I have to put between the brackets to get the menu key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> works for me. Are you sure you wrote it correctly?

```
SendKeys.Send("+({F10})");
```

The parentheses indicates that <kbd>F10</kbd> should be pressed while Shift is **held down**.

Comment: At least under Win8.1 working without round brackets: `SendKeys.SendWait("+{F10}");`

Comment: Actually, it's not working for applications with another functions mapped on Shift+F10 :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Shift+F10 may not work for applications that have other functions mapped to Shift+F10. You can use [keybd_event WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) instead.

```
public static class SendKeyCode
{
    [Flags]
    public enum KeyFlags
    {
        NONE = 1,
        EXTENDEDKEY = 1,
        KEYUP = 2
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SendKey(Keys key, KeyFlags flags = KeyFlags.NONE, byte scanCode = 0, int extraInfo = 0)
        => keybd_event((byte)key, scanCode, (int)flags, extraInfo);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SendKeyCode.SendKey(Keys.Apps);
SendKeyCode.SendKey(Keys.Apps, SendKeyCode.KeyFlags.KEYUP);
```